# R - Merging rows with numerous NA values to another column

Tags: r, row, na

I would like to ask the R community for help with finding a solution for my data, where any consecutive row with numerous NA values is combined and put into a new column.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), B=c(2, "NA", "NA", 5, "NA","NA"), C=c(1,2,"NA",4,5,"NA"), D=c(3,"NA",5,"NA","NA","NA"))

  A  B  C  D
1 1  2  1  3
2 2 NA  2 NA
3 3 NA NA  5
4 4  5  4 NA
5 5 NA  5 NA
6 6 NA NA NA
```

Must be transformed to this:

```
  A  B  C  D  E
1 1  2  1  3  2 NA 2 NA 3 NA NA  5
2 4  5  4 NA  5 NA 5 NA 6 NA NA NA
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Identify consecutive rows that have more than 1 NA value -> combine entries from those consecutive rows into a single combined entiry
2. Place the above combined entry in new column "E" on the prior row

This is quite complex (for me!) and I am wondering if anyone can offer any help with this. I have searched for some similar problems, but have been unable to find one that produces a similar desired output.

Thank you very much for your thoughts--

Comment: I have to ask - why do you want to do this?

Comment: My actual data is in a messy format, where each row represents an individual, followed by a report on that individual which contains numerous line breaks. I am trying to make it such that the rows all represent that 1 individual by combining them onto the same row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tidyr and dplyr:

1. Concatenate values for each row.
2. Keep the concatenated values only for rows with more than one `NA`.
3. Group each “good” row with all following “bad” rows.
4. Use a grouped `summarize()` to concatenate “bad” row values to a single string.

```
df %>%
  unite("E", everything(), remove = FALSE, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(
    E = if_else(
      rowSums(across(!E, is.na)) > 1,
      E,
      ""
    ),
    new_row = cumsum(E == "")
  ) %>%
  group_by(new_row) %>%
  summarize(
    across(A:D, first),
    E = trimws(paste(E, collapse = " "))
  ) %>%
  select(!new_row)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
      A     B     C     D E                   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               
1     1     2     1     3 2 NA 2 NA 3 NA NA 5 
2     4     5     4    NA 5 NA 5 NA 6 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you - for some reason though when attempting this exact script, the data frame is not transformed. It outputs the same table with the column E added, but it is empty. Any idea on why?  # A tibble: 6 × 5
      A B     C     D     E    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 2     1     3     ""   
2     2 NA    2     NA    ""   
3     3 NA    NA    5     ""   
4     4 5     4     NA    ""   
5     5 NA    5     NA    ""   
6     6 NA    NA    NA    ""

Comment: Does your data include `NA` values, or the actual string `"NA"`? If the latter, you would need to change the `rowSums()` line to `rowSums(across(!E, ~ .x == "NA")) > 1`.

Comment: Or, change your `"NA"`s to actual `NA`s first using `df <- tidyr::na_if(df, "NA")`. Which is what I'd recommend in most cases.

Comment: Yes! This absolutely worked. Thanks so so much!!